# how to move a marker on google maps using geofire

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, geofire

```
  let geo = geoFire?.query(at: myLocation!, withRadius: 1000)
     geo?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key:String, location:CLLocation) in
        print("key",key,"location",location)
        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location.coordinate.latitude), longitude: (location.coordinate.longitude))
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = position
        CATransaction.begin()
        let nAnimationDuration: TimeInterval = 1
        // Update this value as per your needs.
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(CFTimeInterval(nAnimationDuration))
        CATransaction.commit()
        marker.icon = self.imageWithImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo-1"), scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 60.0))
        marker.map = self.map1

        self.DriversMarker = marker.position
    })
```

I'm making an app with a Google Maps Activity and I want to place a marker there. How do I set a marker to a location, for example the White House, so that it opens up the info page in google maps I'm getting the single marker but its not moving as its position changes.